# Picture in picture video chat in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, flash

I'm adding a video chat component to an existing application that will have picture in picture functionality. My questions is, due to the "airspace" problem, how can picture in picture be accomplished?

I have two activeX controls, one for the remote video feed, and one for the local video feed. They are both wrapped in their own border and I would like to show the local video and its border in the corner of the larger remote video feed. The local video renders on top of the remote video just fine (although I'm kind of confused by this because I thought that you couldn't have anything on top of an activeX controller due to airspace) but the border that contains the local video gets rendered behind everything so that you cannot see it. I've tried setting the ZIndex of the border, however, this doesn't work.

I'm just wondering how I can accomplish a form of PiP that is similar to what's used in Skype or Microsoft Lync.

EDIT: Would it be possible to simply use a popup window for the PiP? You could create the illusion that it isn't a popup pretty easily. A popup could render on top of the activeX control right?

Comment: "although I'm kind of confused by this because I thought that you couldn't have anything on top of an activeX controller due to airspace" - If you have two ActiveX controls overlapping, one of them has to be on top of the other.

Answer (score 0):

upgrade to .net 4.5. Supposedly they solved the "airspace" problem [(airspace is solved link).](http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2011/09/24/wpf-4-5-%E2%80%93-part-8-no-more-airspace-problems-integrating-wpf-with-win32/)  But, given that you are posting here I'm guessing you can't use .net 4.5?

Comment: Ya I don't think that's an option as I'm working on a small part of a much larger piece of software.

Comment: Also, it doesn't look like that addition is going to make it into the final revision.